# Извлечь данные пользователя

Tags: c#

Создаю программу "Банкомат". Возник вопрос - как сделать чтобы пользователь ввел свой ид, и сразу показало его счет и фио
класс банкомат

```
class Bankomat
{
    public const string Adress = "Эльменя 6, код банкомата 465422";
    public int BankCash { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Cash { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Bankomat(int id, int cash, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Cash = cash;
        Name = name;
    }
```

Основная программа

```
      static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Bankomat Vanya = new Bankomat(146251, 1500, "Петров Иван Иванович");
        Bankomat Alex = new Bankomat(146252, 3400, "Сергеев Александр Сергеевич");
        Bankomat Petya = new Bankomat(146253, 710, "Леонтьев Петр Евгеньевич");

        Console.Write("Введите ваш id пожалуйста: ");
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if ((id == Vanya.Id)||(id == Alex.Id) ||(id == Petya.Id))
        {

        }


        Console.ReadKey();
```

Если ид принадлежит Ване, то выдать только данные Вани.

ps. не предлагать

```
        if (id == Vanya.Id)
        {
              Console.Write("{Vanya.Id} {Vanya.Name} {Vanya.Cash}");
        }else if(id == Alex.Id){
              Console.Write("{Alex.Id} {Alex.Name} {Alex.Cash}");
        }
```

не хочу много условных конструкций, т.к. если будет много пользователей, то код тупо засрется

Comment: Метка `с` не нужна, метки c# достаточно. Обе метки нужны только если у вас взаимодействие двух.

Comment: пройти `foreach` по всем экземплярам `Bankomat`

Comment: А как вы видите решение? Вариантов решения много: `foreach`, `Array`, `List<>`, `switch` плюс Вариант 1.с массивом 2. с ссылкой. (итого 8 вариантов решения) Уточните вопрос.

Comment: Лучший вариант - использовать `Dictionary` с ключом `Id`

Comment: Не пишите, пожалуйста, названия переменных и объектов с большой буквы. Придерживайтесь правилам хорошего тона программирования. Или это Visual Studio сам исправляет когда добавляете сеттеры, геттеры?

Comment: А почему это проблема с#, это ваша проблема, а не проблема c#. Переформулируйте вопрос.

Comment: Просто интересно, почему у каждого юзера свой банкомат? Почему не свой счет в банке, например, или запись в банкомате?

Comment: @tym32167 банкомат один и у каждого пользователя своя учетка

Comment: @Almost а как правильно оформлять?

Comment: @nick_n_a проблема С си шарп, а не у си шарп. У меня с ней проблема, а не у нее

Comment: @dadyaSasha я вижу у вас в коде 3 банкомата :)

Comment: На сайте более 1000 вопросов, касающихся с#, если каждый будет называтся "проблема с с#" то будет бардак полный.

Comment: @tym32167 я мог бы создать класс учетка и унаследовать от банкомата, но мне лень :)

Comment: @dadyaSasha переменные рекомендуется писать строчными буквами, название методов с прописной. Более подробно можно найти по запросу "оформление кода".

Comment: @Almost Спасибо, постараюсь писать правильно

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант с Коллекцией:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Bankomat> BankKollection = new List<Bankomat>();
    BankKollection.Add(new Bankomat(146251, 1500, "Петров Иван Иванович"));
    BankKollection.Add(new Bankomat(146252, 3400, "Сергеев Александр Сергеевич"));
    BankKollection.Add(new Bankomat(146253, 710, "Леонтьев Петр Евгеньевич"));
    Console.Write("Введите ваш id пожалуйста: ");
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    foreach (Bankomat bank in BankKollection)
    {
        if (bank.Id == id)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ФИО : {0}, Счет : {1}, ID : {2}",bank.Name, bank.Cash, bank.Id);
        }
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Или, как советует @iksuy со словарем :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Dictionary<int, Bankomat> BankKollection = new Dictionary<int, Bankomat>();
    BankKollection.Add(1, new Bankomat(1, 1500, "Петров Иван Иванович"));
    BankKollection.Add(2, new Bankomat(2, 3400, "Сергеев Александр Сергеевич"));
    BankKollection.Add(3, new Bankomat(3, 710, "Леонтьев Петр Евгеньевич"));
    Console.Write("Введите ваш id пожалуйста: ");
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    if (BankKollection.Keys.Contains(id))
    {
      Console.WriteLine("ФИО : {0}, Счет : {1}, ID : {2}", BankKollection[id].Name, BankKollection[id].Cash, BankKollection[id].Id);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Выбирайте любой - дело вкуса.

UPD
По совету уважаемого @Alex Krass `foreach` можно заменить на

```
Console.WriteLine(BankKollection.Where(p => p.Key == id).Select(p => p.Value.Id + " " + p.Value.Name + " " + p.Value.Cash).FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: Для foreach не нужен List, Array достаточно. У List тоже есть Find (который в Dictionary => Contains)

Comment: Тогда уж сразу LINQ по List одной строкой без всяких циклов `Console.WriteLine( BankKollection.Where(p => p.Id == id).Select(p => p.Name + " " + p.Cash).FirstOrDefault() );`

Comment: Я думаю можно просто `BankKollection.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == id);` и с этим элементом работать как душе будет угодно...

Comment: `BankKollection` K - Kollection ...